# Pyomo: Create Abstract model and AMPL data

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am just starting with Pyomo and I have a big problem. I want to create an Abstract Model and use AMPL data format to feed it.
The question is a classic transportation problem. I need to find the optimal solution for cost. M means if the shipment is impossible between a given source and destination, a large cost of M is entered.  I need to convert it into AMPL data. Apart from this, I do not know how to create this abstract model. The code for this table and model are shown below. Also after reading this problem, I created the mathematical model as follows.

[the mathematical model that I created][1]

[the classic transportation problem tabel][2]

```
from __future__ import division
from pyomo.environ import *

model = AbstractModel()

model.I = Set()
model.J = Set()

model.a = Param(model.I)
model.b = Param(model.J)
model.cost = Param(model.I,model.J)
model.supply = Var(model.I,model.J)

def obj_expression(model):
    return sum(model.supply[i,j] *  model.cost[i,j] for i in model.I for j in model.J)

model.OBJ = Objective(rule=obj_expression)

def ax_constraint_rule_1(model, i):
    return sum(model.supply[i,j] for j in model.J )<= model.a[i]

def ax_constraint_rule_2(model, j):
    return sum(model.supply[i,j] for i in model.I )>= model.b[j]

model.AxbConstraint = Constraint(model.I, rule=ax_constraint_rule_1)
model.AxbConstraint_2 = Constraint(model.J, rule=ax_constraint_rule_2)

pyomo solve --solver=glpk test.py transportation_data.dat
model.pprint()


set I := D1 D2 D3 ;
set J := S1 S2 S3  ;

param cost :=
S1 D1 3
S1 D2 1
S2 D1 4
S2 D2 2
S2 D3 4
S3 D2 3
S3 D3 3
;

param b :=

D1 7
D2 3
D3 5 ;


param a:=
S1 5
S2 7
S3 3

;
```

Any help with this code? Really need help with the model creation and AMPL data construction.

Thanks anyway

===============================================
The result

````
  File "E:/pycharm_project/test.py", line 28
    pyomo solve --solver=glpk test.py transportation_data.dat
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```




  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoWXA.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwmjb.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are close, I think.  You have a few things to clean up.

You do NOT need `model.m` and `model.n`  I'm not sure what you are trying to do there.

For the sets, I and J, just list them as Set(), because you are providing values for them in your AMPL data.  Like:

```
model.I = Set()     
model.J = Set()
```

In your formulation you are double indexing c[i,j] but in your formulation and data, c is only indexed by `model.I`

Similarly, in your model you are only single-indexing a[i], but you have a double index on it in your data and formulation.

In your constraints, the definitions should only hold a variable for the "for each" part, not the variable you are summing over.

Clean that stuff up, give it a whirl, comment me back if it is still broke.

Edit:  A couple more items.....

I'd recommend naming your parameters and sets intuitively, such as:

`model.supply`, `model.cost`, etc.  Makes it MUCH easier to read & troubleshoot.  :)

============

Edit #2:  Your code cleanup is vastly improved.  A couple cleanup items remain:

In your constraints, you only need to pass variable for the "for each" side of the equation if you are summing over the other variable.  You are making `model.I` constraints here, so this is appropriate:

```
def ax_constraint_rule_1(model, i):  # note removal of j
    return sum(model.supply[i,j] for j in model.J ) <= model.a[i]
```

Note that the summation here is over `j` for each `i` so I changed your for loop also.

flip that around for the other constraint.

your `a, b, cost, supply` don't line up with your data names.  Check them all.  In your data, `a` appears to be `cost[i, j]`

your cost data is also missing some values!

In AMPL syntax, `set` is not capitalized.  If you get it running, it will barf and call out that error.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have changed the code according to your help as shown above(edited the post).And it still can't run properly. Could you please point out the errors in the code after edited? And how about the code for AMPL data?  I want to build a file in AMPL format which can cover the data of that transportation table to feed it. I don't know if the AMPL code is right. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!!  I have changed the code as shown above. But how to display the M in the table? Ignore this M and treat it as if it does not exist or what should I do? And if I want to calculate the value of model.supply, how do I set the AMPL data？Please point out the errors inside code if any mistakes I made. Thanks!!

Comment: Well, it isn't clear what M is in the table.  What context do you have?  I'm assuming that it is some "large" penalty to make those choices infeasible.  I just put in 10, which is a relatively large cost, which would cause it to be chosen last, but that is totally an **assumption**.  You could do same to see if you can get it working.

Comment: M means a large cost between S and D. And the final optimal cost is 46.[link](https://www.me.utexas.edu/~jensen/models/network/net8.html)  This website is that problem.

Comment: OK.  46 is what I got when I solved and it is easy to eyeball that is correct.  So, you an just put in a "large" number for M and it should solve.

Comment: I'm sorry to trouble you. My code does not work, showing that there was an error when GLPK was selected last. Could you please help me compare my code with yours, what parts are different? Or could you let me have a look at your code? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, I'm hesitant to post my code, because this clearly looks like a H/W assignment of some kind.  However, if you just edit and add to your solution above with another code block of of your current code, I'll give a look.  What does the error say?

Comment: Haha, don't worry, I was studying in Ireland. The last semester ended last month. This is not an assignment cause It is a holiday now. My major is EE, so Gams and Pyomo are optimization software that I need to learn. This transportation problem is an example recommended by the teacher. But I didn't find a similar case online. The teacher recommended me to come to this website for help. Really sorry to trouble you ,but I really want you could let me have a look at your code which can really help me to understand this process.Thanks. The error is shown above- the second block.

Comment: posted second solution.  It looks like from your error, you might have the `pyomo solve...` statement *inside* of your program.  That should be a command line entry, not a line of code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, sir!!  I try to add a comment by stack overflow App on my mobile. But it failed. (highly recommend adding that function).I find it! Thanks!

Comment: command line from a terminal prompt in the same folder where both of the files are.  I'm not sure if you can run this within Jupyter notebook.  It is pyomo combining the model file with the data file.  Work the command line....

Comment: Thanks for your help, sir!

Comment: No sweat.  Cool model.  You can "accept" the answer if it was helpful.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my cut:

```
from pyomo.environ import *

model = AbstractModel()

# model.m = Param(within=NonNegativeIntegers)
# model.n = Param(within=NonNegativeIntegers)

model.S = Set()     # Sources
model.D = Set()     # Destinations

model.cost = Param(model.S, model.D)    # cost from S->D
model.supply = Param(model.S)           # supply at source S
model.demand = Param(model.D)           # demad at destination D
model.x = Var(model.S, model.D, domain=NonNegativeReals)

### OBJECTIVE FUNCTION ###

# calculate total cost of decisions
def obj_expression(model):
    return sum(model.x[s, d] * model.cost[s, d] for s in model.S for d in model.D)

model.OBJ = Objective(rule=obj_expression)

### CONSTRAINTS ###

# ensure that supply constraint is met for each source in model.S
def supply_constraint(model, s):
    return sum(model.x[s, d] for d in model.D ) <= model.supply[s] 

# ensure that demand constraint is met for each destination in model.D
def demand_constraint(model, d):
    return sum(model.x[s, d] for s in model.S ) >= model.demand[d] 

model.sup_constraint = Constraint(model.S, rule=supply_constraint)
model.dem_constraint = Constraint(model.D, rule=demand_constraint)


model.pprint()
```

Data file

```
set D := D1 D2 D3 ;
set S := S1 S2 S3 ;

param cost :=
S1 D1 3
S1 D2 1
S1 D3 10
S2 D1 4
S2 D2 2
S2 D3 4
S3 D1 10
S3 D2 3
S3 D3 3
;

param demand := 

D1 7
D2 3
D3 5 ;


param supply :=
S1 5
S2 7
S3 3
;
```

Output:

```
% pyomo solve --solver=glpk transpo_model.py transpo.dat --summary
[    0.00] Setting up Pyomo environment
[    0.00] Applying Pyomo preprocessing actions
4 Set Declarations
    D : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=0, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        Not constructed
    S : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=0, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        Not constructed
    cost_index : Dim=0, Dimen=2, Size=0, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        Virtual
    x_index : Dim=0, Dimen=2, Size=0, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        Virtual

3 Param Declarations
    cost : Size=0, Index=cost_index, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Not constructed
    demand : Size=0, Index=D, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Not constructed
    supply : Size=0, Index=S, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Not constructed

1 Var Declarations
    x : Size=0, Index=x_index
        Not constructed

1 Objective Declarations
    OBJ : Size=0, Index=None, Active=True
        Not constructed

2 Constraint Declarations
    dem_constraint : Size=0, Index=D, Active=True
        Not constructed
    sup_constraint : Size=0, Index=S, Active=True
        Not constructed

11 Declarations: S D cost_index cost supply demand x_index x OBJ sup_constraint dem_constraint
[    0.29] Creating model
[    0.32] Applying solver
[    0.33] Processing results
    Number of solutions: 1
    Solution Information
      Gap: 0.0
      Status: feasible
      Function Value: 46.0
    Solver results file: results.json

==========================================================
Solution Summary
==========================================================

Model unknown

  Variables:
    x : Size=9, Index=x_index
        Key          : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        ('S1', 'D1') :     0 :   5.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
        ('S1', 'D2') :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
        ('S1', 'D3') :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
        ('S2', 'D1') :     0 :   2.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
        ('S2', 'D2') :     0 :   3.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
        ('S2', 'D3') :     0 :   2.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
        ('S3', 'D1') :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
        ('S3', 'D2') :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
        ('S3', 'D3') :     0 :   3.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals

  Objectives:
    OBJ : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Value
        None :   True :  46.0

  Constraints:
    sup_constraint : Size=3
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper
         S1 :  None :  5.0 :   5.0
         S2 :  None :  7.0 :   7.0
         S3 :  None :  3.0 :   3.0
    dem_constraint : Size=3
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper
         D1 :   7.0 :  7.0 :  None
         D2 :   3.0 :  3.0 :  None
         D3 :   5.0 :  5.0 :  None

[    0.33] Applying Pyomo postprocessing actions
[    0.33] Pyomo Finished
```